# Display full details of objects in notebook

Tags: notebooks

Evaluating cells such as

```
i = NetEncoder[{"Image", {64, 64}, ColorSpace -> "Grayscale"}]
NetChain[{
  ConvolutionLayer[32, 5],
  Ramp,
  PoolingLayer[2]
  }, "Input" -> i]
```

always produces

[image]
[image]

where as what I need is the open view

[image]
[image]

, at least for the `NetChain`.

Is there a way to always display full details?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For neural networks, you can do

```
NeuralNetworks`Private`$ExpandNetSummaryBoxByDefault = True;
```

to open them by default.

For most other types of summary boxes, you can use the following:

```
prot = Unprotect@BoxForm`ArrangeSummaryBox;
DownValues@BoxForm`ArrangeSummaryBox = DownValues@BoxForm`ArrangeSummaryBox /.
   HoldPattern@DynamicModule[
      {open_ = False, rest__},
      body_
      ] :> DynamicModule[
     {open = True, rest},
     body
     ];
Protect /@ prot
```

This changes the default state of the generated boxes from closed to open.

Comment: Is there a way of doing this for any summary box without messing with its internals? I am ok to evaluate an additional function on a closed result each time.

Comment: As far as I know, no. The issue is that the state is stored inside a `DynamicModuleBox`, and I don't thinks it's feasible to get the variable and set it after the fact, without even worse messing with the front-end internals...

Comment: @CetinSert you can add a formatting wrapper that would introduce this rule only temporarily. Basically define some function: ``MakeBoxes[OpenedSummaryBoxes[e], form_]:=Internal`InheritedBlock[{BoxForm`ArrangeSummaryBox}, <<lucas's code >>; MakeBoxes[e, form]``